# Не работает Ctrl + V в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, клавиатура, hotkeys

Здравствуйте, встретился с необычной проблемой. В Android Studio не работает  Ctrl + V, пробовал также через контекстное меню, ничего не работает. А вот с Ctrl + C все нормально, копировал текст из студии в браузер, и все работает. Также не работают сочетание клавиш shift + F6 (переименовать), и F6 (переместить), однако с контекстного меню они работают замечательно.
Использую Windows 10, Android Studio 3.0.1

P.S.  Simple Paste работает нормально, и картинки в drawable тоже копируется нормально.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может, студия против копипаста и хочет чтобы вы сами все писали? :)

Comment: как то не смешно

Comment: Попробуй переключиться в английскую раскладку

Comment: я ее и использую, и ничего

Comment: @Developer, ОС какая?

Comment: Я написал, винда 10